# Find the value of k, so that the following lines intersect at the same point

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the value of k, so that the following lines intersect at the same point:

$$3x + y - 2 = 0$$
$$kx + 2y - 3 = 0$$
$$2x - y + 3 = 0$$

How can I resolve this?
thanks

I was able to find that $(-\frac15,\frac{13}5)$ is the intersection of the first and the third line.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I applied that the multiplication of the slopes of the 3 lines is -1, but I do not know if this is correct.

Comment: Okay, so how does that help you? Could you find the intersection of the two lines that don't depend on $k$, and then figure out what to make $k$ so that it also goes through this point?

Comment: I got this result:
-1/5, 13/5
But what should I do to get k and have the condition?

Comment: sum first and third lines. So $5x=5$ and $x=1$. Put $x=1$, in the first line and find $y=-1$. Thus take $x=1$ and $y=-1$ in second line.

Comment: I replaced the values -1/5 and 13/5 in the second equation to get k. I got that k = 11.
I replaced k in the second equation, solved the 3x3 system and got -1/5 and 13/5.
Then is this how it is proven that the condition has been fulfilled?

Comment: It might be useful to edit your progress also into the post and not just mention it in the comments (at least, this might lower the probability that the question is [put on hold](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1117900).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint :**

Solve the system of the first and third equation to find their intersection point. Then, do the same for the pair of the second and third equation oe the first and second. You will find an intersection point dependent on $k$. But you want thwt point to be the same as the first one you calculated. Thus?

Comment: Note that after finding the intersection of the first and third lines, plugging this point straight into the second equation gives a single equation with one unknown (geometrically, choosing $k$ so that the intersection of the other two lines lies on this one as well).